# UILabel - setting font - typeface programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have following code in my Application.

```
tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame];
tmp.tag=1;
tmp.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:18]];
tmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:tmp];
[tmp release];
```

Now, I need to know,

======> how to set "Typeface=bold" through code?

Comment: By "Shadow offset of a label" do you mean size of the label's dropshadow?

Comment: @flashcards - I got the solution no need to find out for shadow.
[tmp setshadowoffset:cgsizemake(1,1)];

Comment: @sagar You should post that as an answer to your own question so it gets saved.  Cheers!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will need to use the name of the `bold` font within the family. To find out if there is a `bold` version of American Typewriter, try outputting

```
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"AmericanTypewriter"]
```

to the console.

In this case, you should use `"AmericanTypewriter-Bold"`.

```
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold"]
```

Comment: @flashcards - no I tried your logic, but my application crashed.

Comment: Hmmm...looks like fontNamesForFamilyName is a static method on UIFont that takes in a family name.  I will fix my answer now.  Did you try using "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"?

Comment: @sagar - There is no space between "American Typewriter". I think you have put space between them.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried and it should be `[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:18.f]`

Comment: I figured that if I misspecified the fontWithName, I would get an error. However iOS just defaults to standard font. Can get a list of font names and typefaces [here](https://gist.github.com/shannoga/1008678)

Answer (score 20):

What about using the setter property:

```
// Create a string  
NSString *text = @"You are getting sleepy.";

// Get a font to draw it in  
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:28];

// Draw the string  
[text drawInRect:(CGRect)
withFont:font];
```

Comment: This is only useful if you want to use the system font. @Spark was not using a system font.

Answer (score 17):

Just NSLog The font you want get:

```
NSLog(@" %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"American Typewriter"]);
```

And you get the array:

```
(
    "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight",
    "AmericanTypewriter-Light",
    "AmericanTypewriter-Bold",
    AmericanTypewriter,
    "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold",
    "AmericanTypewriter-Condensed"
)
```

Use any you need in Code:

```
UILabel * loading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 402, 150, 25)];
    [loading setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:12.0]];
    [loading setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [loading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loading setText:@"Loading ..."];
    [self.view addSubview:loading];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the iOS supported font names in this site [iOSfonts](http://iosfonts.com/).
Take preview of your exact string to find the best font and use it like mentioned in above answers

```
UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 150, 50)];
    [loading setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12.0]];
    [loading setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [loading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loading setText:@"My Label Title"];
    [self.view myLabel];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @devinfoley wrote, you have to add `-Bold` to the `fontName` you're using. For me it doesn't work with `fontNamesForFamilyName`, instead I'm using `fontWithName:size`. Maybe it works if you create the `UILabel` programmatically. In my case I'm just setting the `font` inside the extension of my `UILabel` in `awakeFromNib` and set this extension as `class` in the `Identity Inspector` for my specific `UILabel`. With `self.font.pointSize` you can set the `fontSize` inside the `Interface Builder` and can handle it better if you have more UI elements.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{

    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font-Bold" size:self.font.pointSize]];
}
```

If your `font` doesn't work you should print all `fonts` of the family, so you can see if you wrote the `fontName` wrong. This way you also can check if there is a `bold` font available, if its not printed you don't have this option.

```
NSLog (@"Available Fonts: %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Your Font"]);
```

More `font` stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529661/1141395

Answer (score 0):

**Swift update**

If you've already added the font to the app (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)) you can use Swift's `extension` feature with, as example, a `UILabel` and the Roboto font:

```
extension UILabel {

    func setFont(style: String, size: Int){
        self.font = UIFont(name: style, size: CGFloat(size))
    }

    struct FontStyle {
        public static let italic: String = "Roboto-LightItalic"
        public static let normal: String = "Roboto-Light"
        public static let thin: String = "Roboto-Thin"
    }
}
```

`Roboto-LightItalic` and `Roboto-Light` are the TTF's font file names. Then, you can simply call

```
someUILabel.setFont(style: UILabel.FontStyle.normal, size: 20)
```