# How to set the "TypeFace" for font?

Tags: iphone

I want to mention the font name,font size and typeface values in my application.

I mentioned the name and size.

But I can't do the typeface value.

So please tell me how to set that value.

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302833/uilabel-setting-font-typeface-programmatically-in-iphone

Comment: When you say you want to "mention it", do you mean you want to display the values somewhere in your application, or you want to be able to set the values in your code (rather than Interface Builder)?

Comment: AT THE TIME OF DECLARE THE LABEL.I WANT TO MENTION THE TYPEFACE VALUE FOR LABEL

Answer (score 1):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
```

or for a label:

```
UILabel *label =[[UILabel alloc] init];
label.font = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"];
```