# Does iOS dev has build-in fixed width font?

Tags: ios, uifont, fixed-width

The font called from [UIFont boldSystemFontWithSize xx] is not fixed-width, I don't know the exact name of this system font (iOS 6).

I'm wondering if there is a built-in fixed-width font? Otherwise I have to embed a new font to my app.

PS: maybe iOS 7 system font is fixed-width, LOL

Thanks guys.

Comment: I think courier new is a built in monospaced font.

Comment: YES, it is, but is it iOS built-in? Or...do you know how to check all the font that built-in iOS system? THANKS, your answer is so fast !

Comment: Yes it is built in, see Tyler's answer for a complete list. You can also get a list of all fonts off the device programatically, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529661/488611

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the list of built-in fonts available on iOS: http://iosfonts.com.

Courier looks like the only monospace font in there.

Comment: Just to be clear: American Typewriter is not a fixed width typeface. (Part of its elegance is its subtle proportional spacing.)

Comment: According to that website, iOS 7 introduced a font called "Menlo" which is a sans-serif monospaced font.