# List of fonts that can be used with SpriteKit's labelNodeWithFontNamed method

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

How can I get the list of font names that can be used with `SpriteKit`'s `labelNodeWithFontNamed` method?

There is a method of `SKLabelNode` where I can specify the font name but I would like to know which fonts are supported and what are their names.

Example:

```
[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
```

Comment: Check this link [How to check if a font is available in version of iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529593/how-to-check-if-a-font-is-available-in-version-of-ios)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Refer to [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com) They show you how the actual font looks like, it's descriptive name and its code name as well as the iOS version a specific font was added.

Use only the code names of each font, like `AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to get your fonts with names by this code:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family]) {
        NSLog(@"--- %@",name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great for iOS. However I can't get UIFont from MacOS.