# Xcode: Add default custom font to SKLabelNode with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have searched everywhere, but I can only find how to change the UILabel fonts and can't find anywhere that teaches how to change the default SKLabelNode font. How do I do that in Xcode with swift?

I have already added the font to the Info.plist

I have also tried to add an extension that would change the default font, but it also didn't work

Comment: Just for clarification, are you looking to change the font that all `SKLabelNodes` use? Or are you looking to change a particular node away from the default?

Comment: I want to make the change to all of them

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/ 
Don't much familiar with Swifty, but you could subclass it or make a category.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changing the font for one SKLabelNode

As you probably already know, you can change the font of a `SKLabelNode` using the `fontName` property.

```
let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
```

[image]

```
label.fontName = "Arial"
```

[image]

### Changing the font for all the SKLabelNode(s)

Now, if I'm not wrong you want to change the `fontName` for **all the labels** in your scene.

First of all we need an easy way to visit all the nodes in your scene graph. I mean, not only the direct children of the scene but every child of child of child...

### Visiting the scene graph

The best way I can imagine is implementing a `visit` extension in `SKNode`

```
extension SKNode {
    func visit(logic: (node:SKNode) -> ()) {
        logic(node:self)
        children.forEach { $0.visit(logic) }
    }
}
```

Now `SKNode` has a `visit` function that receive a closure. The closure gets applied to the current node and to every children. Then the process is recursively repeated until there are new descendants.

### Launching the recursion

Now in you `GameScene` you can add this code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    func changeFonts() {
        visit { (node) -> () in
            if let label = node as? SKLabelNode {
                label.fontName = "Arial"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, when you're ready invoke `changeFonts()`.
It should do the job.

*Just remember to use [a font available in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734855/list-of-fonts-that-can-be-used-with-spritekits-labelnodewithfontnamed-method).*

Comment: I wasn't with enough time to test before, sorry. Just adding that it should be called after declaring the `SKLabelNode`s in each Scene. It worked fine, beautiful answer.  Thanks! :)