# Adding custom font (Impact) to iOS project not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

This is a topic that looks like many others have struggled with. I'm trying to add the 'Impact' font to my iOS project. To do so, I perform the following steps:
1. Add the Impact.ttf file to my project.
2. Ensure that the Impact.ttf file is in fact added to the project Target.
 
3. Check 'Copy Bundle with Resources' in the target Build Phases and make sure the Impact.ttf file is included .
 
4. In My-Project-Name-Info.plist, I added the "Fonts provided by application" option and set Impact.ttf as item 0 in the array.
5. Open the font file with Font Book and make sure I'm referencing the font by the correct name. In this case, Impact is the correct name. 

 
I used the following code snipped to see all available fonts in the project, and 'Impact' is not one of them:

```
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", family); 
    for (NSString *name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family]) {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

When inspecting the value of UIFont in the following snippet, I get nil.

```
UIFont *impactFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Impact" size:36.0f];
```

I've quadruple checked all spellings and gone through each step multiple times. I've also used the following resources (and many more) to troubleshoot the problem.

- [Custom font in iOS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631292/custom-font-in-ios-not-working)
- [iOS custom font robot bold not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811737/ios-custom-font-robot-bold-not-working)
- [Common mistakes with adding custom fonts to your iOS app](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

**One item to note:** If I open Impact.ttf with font book, it says that the font is not installed. I click to install the font, and get a warning that there are duplicate Impact fonts installed. To fix this warning, I click 'Resolve duplicates automatically' and the font shows as installed. However, if I open the file again, the font shows as not installed. 
*I'm not sure if having the font installed in Font Book is necessary for it to correctly be recognized in my project* .

Thank you very much for your help! I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I feel like I've exhausted all resources and links here on SO and other sites.

Comment: Your steps look good. Since it sounds like you've been pretty thorough already, I would make a new project that simply tests whether you can load the font. If it works, then maybe you'll see what's different between your projects. If it doesn't, you can post a link to the example project and people here can take a look at it.

Comment: I don't think that the font need to be install on your system for it to work on your project. If you had any enlightenment on the subject I'd be glad to profit from it :) Since I'm struggling with something similar. As for me to make it worth, it was working and it simply stopped...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the answer you want, but is a solution you could use to move on. 
That is what i use on my projects, simple and useful https://github.com/deni2s/IBCustomFonts

Hope you can find a better solution!