# Nativescript/Angular: Custom fonts not applied in iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am building a Nativescript Angular app with code sharing ([TNS Code Sharing](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro)). Trying to apply Roboto Regular font, but it seems it's not working. I've seen that there are tons of questions about iOS and custom fonts out there, but none of given answers solves my problem, so I guess it has something to do with the fact that I'm using @nativescript/schematics (code sharing) setup.

If I use file name instead of font name, it works fine on Android, but whatever I specify as font-family, it never works on iOS.

Thanks folks.

Here's the code:

Font file location: `src/app/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`

src/_app-common.scss

```
.roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
}
```

src/app/pages/my/my.component.tns.html

```
<Label [nsRouterLink]="['/about']" text="About" class="h1 text-center roboto" textWrap="true"></Label>
```

package.json

```
{
      "name": "appname",
      "nativescript": {
        "id": "no.app.id",
        "tns-android": {
          "version": "4.2.0"
        },
        "tns-ios": {
          "version": "4.2.0"
        }
      },
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "android": "tns run android --bundle",
        "ios": "tns run ios --bundle"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "nativescript-angular": "~6.1.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "~4.2.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^6.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.0.3",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.0",
        "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
        "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.16.0",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2",
        "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

When you create your project with nativescript-schematics (mobile and web code sharing) with `ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-shared-app --shared` the folder structure is little bit different than in standard nativescript application. In nativescript app you have `app/` inside the root, and here you get `src/app/`. In this case, placing custom fonts in `src/app/fonts/` worked for Android but not for iOS. When I moved them to `src/fonts/` iOS picked them up too. Not sure if this works now on Android too, it would be dumb to have them doubled or symlinked, but I will check it out as soon as I test it on Android.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, did you do anything else? I am trying to do the same with both font awesome and a google font. None of them seem to get picked up in my Code sharing app. For now i am only testing IOS builds. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Placing `fonts/` in `src/` solved my problem. Other than that, make sure that you use **font name** for iOS and file name for Android in your CSS, in case of Roboto for example
`* { 
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular', 'Roboto Regular', 'Roboto'; 
}`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Vladimir. I finally found it. You NEED the 3 items in the font-family definition apparently.
font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'Font Awesome 5 Free Regular', 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

Comment: When i prepare build using XCODE I get this error "You don’t have permission to save the file “fonts” in the folder <APP_NAME>" any idea? I put fonts folder as src/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Roboto is not a standard iOS font, so if you haven't included the Roboto font in your `fonts/` directory, it won't be available on iOS.

To determine which fonts are available on your iPhone (and what the names are that you should be addressing them by), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529661/2708650) to another StackOverflow question (relevant source copied below).

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I know it's not standard, should have mentioned that. I did put Roboto-Regular.ttf file in `src/app/fonts`, and it works fine in web app and Android app (with appropriate font-family), but it fails to apply in iOS. I updated my question to include file path where the file is, since that might have something to do with it. In standard {N} it goes to `app/fonts/` and when using nativescript-schematics app folder is located inside `src/`.

Comment: I am using a custom font in my app, which I have included in `app/fonts`. It loads on both iOS and Android from this location. I recommend checking to see how Roboto appears in the output from the snippet I posted above. As a quick-and-dirty solution, you can edit that into the `main.m` file in the generated project, then build and run through Xcode just to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The postscript name of the font seems to be `Roboto-Regular`, so Try this,

```
.roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register the font on your `main.ts` launch event

```
app.on(app.launchEvent, function (args: app.ApplicationEventData) {
    ...
    if (isIOS) {
      var fontModule = require("ui/styling/font");
      fontModule.ios.registerFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have to do that as long you keep your files inside fonts folder, those will be registered by default (https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/05c2460fc4989dae4d7fa1ee52f6d54e0c3113f5/tns-core-modules/ui/styling/font.ios.ts#L225).

Answer (score 0):

seems your file location is : `src/app/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`

app.css **font-family should be same as file name** :

```
.roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
}
```

add class in html file like this

```
<Label text="About" class="roboto" ></Label>
```

Comment: Hi, I've read (currently waiting for Android phone to test it), that you should do it like this `font-family: 'Roboto-Regular', 'Roboto Regular';` since Android wants to know file name and iOS font name.