# swift bold title in navigation bar

Tags: swift

installed fonts for `title navigation bar`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size:50 )!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.purple]
```

how do I make it bold ?

found, that can be done so, but after all the fine print I already set

```
.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
```

Comment: Use font attributes to get the desired font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to say that font you want to use is named **OpenSans** with style **Bold**

```
"OpenSans-Bold"
```

So use this:

```
.font: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 50)!
```

Comment: tnx, for  `Tsukushi A Round Gothic ` font how will be?  `Tsukushi A Round Gothic-Bold ` - dont work

Comment: 筑紫A丸ゴシック-Bold maybe this? :D

Comment: i download from "font book". he have regular and bold styles, but i cant use bold style

Comment: @Lolidze can you send link of website where you have downloaded it?

Comment: i just opened "font book" in mac os. and search "Tsukushi A Round Gothic". soft found it and i download it from "font book"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184711/discussion-between-lolidze-and-robert-dresler).

Comment: u found it ? i will search link for this font

Comment: i didnt found link, but i uploaded https://www.sendspace.com/file/iydguz

Comment: @Lolidze have you tried `TsukushiAMaruGothic-Bold`?

Comment: Please continue discussion in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184711/discussion-between-lolidze-and-robert-dresler

Answer (score 1):

You should use the bold version of Open Sans. Instead of "OpenSans" use the string that corresponds with the bold version ex. "OpenSans-Bold"

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size:50 )!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.purple]
```

The font name will be specific to your environment.

Comment: tnx, for  `Tsukushi A Round Gothic ` font how will be?  `Tsukushi A Round Gothic-Bold ` - dont work

Comment: Please see this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147786/7978419) @Lolidze It will have the answer that you need.